# Mongodb/Mongoose: How to properly implement findOneAndUpdate on an express route

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to use the findOneAndUpdate() method to update update an existing model(Account) with the data the user enters on a html update form.
So if the user only decides to update the phone number field, only the phone number field is updated and the two remaining fields stays the same.

The Account schema:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var accountSchema = new Schema({
    // Reference to the user model in session.
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

    // User's account information displayed on user's home page
    first_name :    {type: String},
    last_name  :    {type: String},
    phone_number:   {type: String}

    },
    {timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }}
    );

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

Here is the code for my route:

```
    app.get('/support', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
      var account = Account({user: req.user});
      Account.findOne({user: req.user}, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500);
            return;
        }
        console.log(account.first_name)
        res.render('support', {user: req.user, account: account});
      });
    });

    app.post('/support', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
      var id = req.params.account._id;

      Account.findByIdAndUpdate(id, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error, no entry found');
        }
        doc.first_name  = req.body.first_name || doc.first_name;
        doc.last_name  = req.body.last_name || doc.last_name;
        doc.phone_number  = req.body.phone_number || doc.phone_number;
        doc.save();
      })
      res.redirect('/home');
    });
```

The get request works fine. I can access the account model on the get request for displaying user details to the user but, the update route is not doing anything. I know I am missing something on the update post route setup.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just realized that you're using `findByIdAndUpdate` wrong. My first answer is still valid though and can be found after this.
`findByIdAndUpdate`s second argument isn't a callback but an object containing the values to be changed. When used correctly, you do not have to call `.save()` at the end of the request.
So, the correct way to update the schema would be this:

```
Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.account._id, {
    $set:{
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        // etc
    }
}, {new: true}, function(err, updatedDoc){
    // do stuff with the updated doc
});
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
the `doc.save()` also takes a callback, just as `findByIdAndUpdate` does. So you have to nest another callback inside your save function, and there you can then redirect.

Here's how I'd do it (using promises):

```
app.post('/support', function(req, res, next){
    Account.findOne({_id: req.params.account._id}).exec()
    .then(function(doc){
        doc.first_name = req.body.first_name || doc.first_name;
        // etc ...
        return doc.save();
    })
    .then(function(){
        // Save successful! Now redirect
        res.redirect('/home');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // There was an error either finding the document or saving it.
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

And here's how you include an external promise library - I'm using the ['q' library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
// app.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the speedy reply... I just have one question. Would I need to install promises before the second example(using promises) would work?

Comment: Yes, you have to use an external promise library since mongoose's own promise library is deprecated. I'll update my answer to include promises :)

Comment: Well thanks David, after some tweaking with your code review, I was able to get my update routes working. I will post my solution here later. I can't wait to finish up.
Once again thanks alot.

Comment: @omosofe did you get the solution to this in the end?